# How to Install libz.1.2.3.dylib on OS X 10.7?

Tags: python, gzip, iphone

I want to install libz.1.2.3.dylib to use for building an iPhone app. OS X 10.7.4 has libz.1.2.5.dylib. But, the server I'm sending the gzipped data to has zlib 1.2.3 (used by Python). And, when it tries to decompress the gzipped data, it gets an error:

```
encoded = 'H4sIAAAAAAAAA4uuVspTslLySi0uTlVwSs0rSS0qUdJRygSKGQHpAiWraCVDS0MTY0MLUwszc6XYWh2ojvyMPAX3osSMxFyoekO4egsTc1NjY3NLCxOE+qDEvJR8BZfSlFSoclNDA2O4DnMLc3MDCwMDAwugjlgAp2IZdpUAAAA='
>>> decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)>>> zlib.decompress(decoded)Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
>>> zlib.decompress(decoded, 16)Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -2 while preparing to decompress data
```

But, it works with the Python on my local machine.

So, I'm guessing that building the iOS app with libz.1.2.3.dylib will fix things. If that's the best way, how do I install that? Otherwise, is there a way to make zlib 1.2.5 (on OS X 10.7) play nice with libz 1.2.3 (on server)?

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is unfortunately incorrect.  All versions of zlib can decompress compressed data produced by all other versions of zlib, forward and back.  Going back to 1.2.3 won't help.

The problem is that you have a gzip stream, but you are asking zlib to decode it as a zlib stream.  gzip and zlib are different wrappers around deflate compressed data.  You need to ask zlib to decode a gzip stream.

You can do that with the `wbits` parameter.  Try `zlib.decompress(decoded, 31)`.

**Update:**

I took a look at the Python [documentation on their zlib module](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html), and it's horrible.  The design has problems as well.  The page is titled "12.1. zlib — Compression compatible with gzip".  However the `zlib.compress` and `zlib.compressobj` functions compress to the zlib format, which is *not* compatible with gzip!  Furthermore, there appears to be no way to provide an option to `zlib.compress` to produce the gzip format, which the [actual zlib library](http://zlib.net/) supports.  (There is nothing analogous to the option mentioned above for `zlib.decompress`, which in fact does permit the decoding of gzip input.)

The documentation for the `wbits` parameter of `zlib.decompress` does not mention the possibility of `wbits` values above 15 and what they do.  In fact it says that the highest value is 15.

It makes no sense to provide a `wbits` parameter for `zlib.decompress`, but not `zlib.compress`.  The whole point for the usual values (8..15) is to allow the production of compressed streams that require less memory to decompress.  If you can't produce them, then there's never a case where you could provide a `wbits` parameter of 8..14 and expect it to work.

The documentation for negative `wbits` values says that the standard gzip header is suppressed.  They managed to make two mistakes in that one.  First, suppression is what the compressor would do, by suppressing the wrapper around the deflate data.  A decompressor in that case simply decodes raw deflate data, not looking for a wrapper.  Second, it would be a zlib wrapper that is ignored if produced by `zlib.compress`, not a gzip wrapper which the module can't produce anyway.

I think I'll just stop reading it now, since I keep finding problems.